# The probability that a point has max,min $x$,$y$ among $n$ points

Tags: probability

There are $n$ points randomly by uniform distribution distributed in the plane. We know that no two points have the same $(x ,y)$. What is the probability that a point has one of these properties?

- it has maximum value of $x$ and maximum value of $y$ among $n$ points.
- it has maximum value of $x$ and minimum value of $y$ among $n$ points.
- it has minimum value of $x$ and maximum value of $y$ among $n$ points.
- it has minimum value of $x$ and maximum value of $y$ among $n$ points.

#### My solution:

First, I am going to answer a trivial question to clarify my solution. What is the probability that a point has minimum value of $x$ among $n$ points and what is the probability that this set contains a point with minimum value of $x$? Since there is no bound on $x, y$ and $n$ points are random, I assume exactly one point has the minimum value of $x$. The probability that every point has the minimum value of $x$ is $1/n$, So the probability that a set of $n$ points has a point with minimum value of $x$ is $\sum_{i=1}^n{1/n} = 1$.

To answer the original question, There are $n$ different values of $x$ and $n$ different values of $y$ (*I assume this is true, If not I should calculate the expected number of different $x$s and $y$s*), the point must have a specific $(x,y)$, so the probability that a point has one of the above properties is $1/{n^2}$. So the probability that a set of points have one of the above properties is $4 * \sum_{i=1}^n{1/{n^2}} = 4/n$.

Is this a right answer to my question?

Comment: I'm confused by your question. Let's give some concrete notation to this: Let your $n$ randomly chosen points be denoted $(x_1, y_1), \ldots, (x_n, y_n)$ and let $(x, y)$ be an arbitrary point in the plane. When you ask "what is the probability that a point has a maximum value of $x$ and a maximum value of $y$" things get confusing. Are you really asking what is the probability that the maximum of $x_1, \ldots, x_n$ is $x$ and the maximum of $y_1, \ldots, y_n$ is $y$? If so, the answer is, of course, zero but it would be useful to consider the density instead. Is that your question?

Comment: The question remains: no uniform distribution over $\Bbb R$ exists.

Comment: @jjet Yes, I am asking among the $x_1 \cdots x_n$ and $y_1 \cdots y_n$ the probability that a point has the maximum of $x$ and $y$. Why this probability is zero?!!!

Comment: @ParclyTaxel I meant there is no bias on the position of points.

Comment: First, let me further clarify my take on your question. By "uniform distribution in a plane", I had assumed you meant the continuous, bivariate uniform distribution on the unit interval, $[0, 1]^2$. To answer your question, the probability that any continuous random variable is equal to any single number is always zero. That is, if $Z$ is continuous, then $P(Z=z)=0$ for every $z$. That's just a fact of calculus. Instead, you have to consider the density or "limiting probability", $f(z)=P(z \le Z<z+h)/h$. Does this make sense?

Comment: @jjet yes I got it. But something confuses me. There are $n$ points, named $p_1 \cdots p_n$ and each having a $(x,y)$. Surely one of them has minimum $x$. If we select one of them randomly, The probability of selecting the minimum is $1/n$, right?

Comment: Now it sounds like you're question simpler. My understand is that you want to know the probability that a randomly selected pair from the set, say $(x_i, y_i)$, will have one of four properties, where the first property is $x_i=\max\{x_1, \ldots, x_n\}$ and $y_i=\max\{y_1, \ldots, y_n\}$ and so on. Is that right? If so, that's not a trivial problem to solve.

Comment: @jjet I need to solve the probability that a randomly selected pair from the set will have one of four properties, When points are distributed each one has a $(x,y)$ and after distribution we know what $x$s and $y$s are. To get the probability that a point will have one of 4 properties, it must be the probability that a point has $max_x$ and $max_y$. Since there is one $x$ with max value and one $y$ with max value among $x$s and $y$s, a point must have a specific $(x,y)$ that is $1/n * 1/n$. It is not right?

Comment: @jjet My view of this problem is to select $n$ random $x$s and $n$ random $y$s. Then randomly pair them together, then the desired probability should be $1/n^{2}$. I donno if it is right

Comment: Ok I finally see what you're saying. I'll put the solution in the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The setup of this problem is as follows. There are $n$ pairs $(X_1, Y_1), \ldots, (X_n, Y_n)$, where each $X_i$ and each $Y_j$ are independently drawn from a Uniform distribution. (Note, this is actually a "distribution-free" problem so the fact that the random variables are uniformly distributed is inconsequential.) Suppose we randomly select the pair $(X_i, Y_i)$. It will be helpful if we let $A$ denote the event that $X_i$ is either the maximum or the minimum of the set of $X$ values: $A=X_i=\max\{X_i\} \cup X_i=\min\{X_i\}$. Similarly, let $B=Y_i=\max\{Y_i\} \cup Y_i=\min\{Y_i\}$. Mathematically, you're question can then be stated as $P(A \cup B)$. Using the inclusion-exclusion principle, we can rewrite this as
$$ P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cap B) $$
It is straightforward to show that $P(A)=P(B)=\frac 2 n$. Also, the events $A$ and $B$ are independent so we have that $P(A \cap B)=P(A)P(B)=\frac 4 {n^2}$. Therefore, $P(A \cup B)=\frac 4 n - \frac 4 {n^2}$. You're original answer was close but it didn't consider the fact that you were implicitly double-counting $P(A \cap B)$. However, if $n$ is large, then that term is very small.